# AWK converting GB, TB to TiB

Tags: bash, awk

I need to convert GB and TB to TiB (bash/awk)

My Data comes like this

```
6TB
100GB
80.13GB
10.53TB
```

My awk match command is like this

```
{ match($3, /([[:digit:]]+)([[:alpha:]]+)/, any)
if (any[2]=="GB") { size=any[1]*0.000909; }
else if(any[2]=="TB") { size=any[1]*0.909494; }
```

I have problem with when the data is with decimal, for ex:
`10.53TB` converted to `48.20 TiB`

How do I fix my match or any other way?

Comment: `numfmt --from=si --to=iec-i --suffix=B <file`

Comment: please update the question with the expected output

Comment: You owe it to the community to show how you are using it via expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem with the regular expression for numbers. [[:digit:]]+ will not match a numeric string containing decimals. [[:digit:].]+ should be correct.

Additionally, I want to use powers instead of numbers for unit conversions.

example(GNU awk):

```
{
    match($1, /([0-9.]+)([TG]B)/, any)
    e = any[2] == "GB" ? 9 : 12
    printf "%.2f TiB\n", any[1] * 10^e / 2^40
}
```

Answer (score 2):

##### Like this, reusing the most code from you

Added the `.` in the regex:

```
$ awk '                                           
    {
        match($1, /([[:digit:].]+)([A-Z]{3})/, any)
        printf "%.2f TiB\n", (any[2]=="GB") ? any[1]*0.000909 : any[1]*0.909494  
        
    }
' file
```

[image: warning]

- you don't have `$3` from your input file, but only `$1` == `$0` column here
- better test `[A-Z]` UPPERCASE only in the second *capture group*
- you need to add `.` in the regex, like I do, to treat *floats*

[image: note]

- I use *ternary operator* here. The skeleton is `(cond) ? res_true : res_not_true`. The parenthesis are optional.

##### Intput

```
6TB
100GB
80.13GB
10.53TB
```

##### Output

```
5.46 TiB
0.09 TiB
0.07 TiB
9.58 TiB
```

##### The regular expression matches as follows:

| Node | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `(` | group and capture to any[1]: |
| `[[:digit:].]+` | any character of: digits (like \d), '.' (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `)` | end of a group 1 |
| `(` | group and capture to any[2]: |
| `[A-Z]{3}` | any UPPERCASE alphabet (3 times) |
| `)` | end of group 2 |

Answer (score 0):

here's a generic function that can handle every metric order of magnitude (`every 1000`) from `10 ^ 0` all the way to the latest `"quetta"`, or `10 ^ 30`, and convert them to binary `TiB` ::

```
echo '
   6TB
   100GB
   80.13GB
   10.53TB
   61277761
   191.101367 EB' |
```

---

```
gawk 'function ____(__,_,___) { 
     return \
        sprintf("%*.*f TiB", (_+=_+=_^=_<_) * (_+_), _+_+_,
          __ * (_+--_+_)^(_++ * index(___ = "KMGTPEZYRQ", 
         substr(__ = toupper(__), 
                       match(__, "[" (___) "]"), !!_))) / _^(_++*_)) 

     } BEGIN { OFS = "\v\r\t\t| "
                FS = RS
           CONVFMT = "%.250g" } $++NF = ____($!_)'
```

---

```
6TB
        |                   5.456968210638 TiB
100GB
        |                   0.090949470177 TiB
80.13GB
        |                   0.072877810453 TiB
10.53TB
        |                   9.576979209669 TiB
61277761
        |                   0.000055731799 TiB
191.101367 EB
        |           173805680.788063913584 TiB
```

- fun trivia : 1 binary TiB is both `2^40` and `4^20`